# Android search dialog does not open on button/action press

Tags: java, android, xml, search, android-manifest

I need some second eyes on this. I have followed the basic instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) to set up search in the application I'm working on, yet I am unable to make the search dialog appear, both using the device search button and my search action on the action bar.

As far as the action bar is concerned, I have confirmed that onSearchRequested is being called on the activity when the action is pressed. Any resources referenced in these files are existing - the application runs without errors.

My searchable.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/search_label"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
    </searchable>
```

The activity definition of my search handling activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

For each activity in which I would like search, I have added:

```
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".SearchActivity" />
```

When I press any of the buttons mentioned above, nothing happens. Nothing happens in logcat either. Since onSearchRequested is being called, I'm suspecting there is something wrong with my configuration, but I have been unable to find it so far.

In case it might be important, I can point out that my SearchActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, and I've made a bit of a fool of myself. See, the project I'm working on has a core android application supporting specializations based on it. I'm adding search to the former, but it is of course necessary to modify the AndroidManifest.xml in the dependent module, as it is the one that matters when that module is deployed. Modifying the core modules  manifest doesn't help anything.

And I, of course, was adding these bits to the AndroidManifest.xml in the core module, not in the module meant for deployment, which meant I wasn't actually defining anything. No wonder nothing happened.

Comment: Not sure whether or not to just delete this question. Indeed, the actual problem was one far more general and basic than the question itself, so its a bit misleading. On the other hand, others might get stuck in this rut.